Orca slicer calibration tolerance test
I've done the calibration tests in Orca Slicer for my 3D printer, but I have no idea where to insert information for the tolerance test! I've seen instructions of how to do the test on multiple websites but they don't give this information.
Does anyone know how to solve this, or did I just waste filament doing an obsolete calibration test?

Tolerance isn't set up in the slicer. It's added in your CAD software when designing your model. It's used when you have parts that have to fit together. You add the tolerance to get the fit you need between those parts. For instance, parts that should be able to move (like a print in place hinge) need a bigger tolerance than parts that should fit very firmly so they don't come apart.
The Orca tolerance test lets you examine those various tolerances, so that when you need to add them in your model, you know how much you need to add for each type of fit.

That definitely clears things up. I won't look for any settings to change in Orca now, and I'll do more research on how to use it with CAD. Thanks for your clear response!
